# Back of the envelope Oraclize callback cost calculations for

Tags: contract-design, gas, oracles

How does one do a back of the envelope calculation about how much the Oraclize callback will cost? Does it cost more if a query is returning a large amount versus a small amount of data? Does it cost more if you are asking Oraclize to search for specific json keys in the result of your query? For example, does the callback for

`xml(http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss).rss.channel.item.0.title`

cost more than

```
xml(http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss).rss
```

?

Or does it only depend on the computation associated with your actual __callback function?